# What is T in this code

Tags: go

What really T is in this piece of code? recursive deceleration?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T func() T

func main() {
    var a T
    a = func() T {
        return a
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", a)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/zt4CBXgrmI

Edit: I have been using Go for more than a year.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a [function type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types). In the declaration, T is a parameterless function that returns a T, so a function that returns a function. That is the type declaration. a is of this type T.

a is a function that returns itself, so these lines basically all do the same:

```
fmt.Printf("%#v", a)
fmt.Printf("%#v", a())
fmt.Printf("%#v", a()()()()())
```

I can't think of a good use for this, but then again, I'm far from experienced in Go.

Comment: a is easy, It returns itself, but my question is T.

Comment: T is the type declaration for this function type. T is a function that returns a T. It's kinda like a recursive declaration. :o)

Comment: Use case: this is used by Rob Pike in [his talk about lexical scanning in Go](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE&feature=player_detailpage#t=846).

Comment: Need to note that T is not a function that returns itself, it's a function which returns T. Example:  http://play.golang.org/p/_MAiiMQH63 :)

Comment: @Kluyg That's right. As I wrote, a is a function that returns itself. a is of type T, which is a function that returns a T. It's not necessary the same T according to the declaration. 'returning itself' is how it is implemented in a.

Answer (score 0):

GolezTrol is correct. `T` is type. `t` is variable of `T` type. 
`t` contain reference to function

I added type `S` of function that returns `int` instead of `S` and compared how it work and what it returns

http://play.golang.org/p/2VRqmMVQR9